# Batch-file to recursively copy many listed files to one specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

I am attempting to run a batch file that will recursively search a drive for a list of specific files I'm looking for. I believe I've almost to down but am having issues with the recursive part.

Right now, I'm working between two batch files that I've created based on other threads I've read.

When running this batch file I want the command to open the text file that is located in LISTFOLDER and read over all of the file names with in this text file. Which the below script does beautifully. The only issue with the below script is that it doesn't search recursively through the FILESPATH.

```
@echo off

set LISTFOLDER=C:\vbk\txt\test
set FILESPATH=C:\
set DESTPATH=C:\vbk\dest\test

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b ^"%LISTFOLDER%\*.txt^"') do (call :COPY_FILES "%LISTFOLDER%\%%i")

pause
exit

:COPY_FILES
for %%i in (%1) do set DEST=%%~ni
for /f "usebackq delims==" %%i in (%1) do echo xcopy /qv "%FILESPATH%\%%i" "%DESTPATH%\*"
```

After doing some more research I found a command that recursivally searched through FILESPATH but wouldn't read the text file and it appears to be search for the entire path of the text file (ex. C:\vbk\txt\test\test.txt) vs the information within the text file.

```
@echo off

set LISTFOLDER=C:\vbk\txt\test
set FILESPATH=C:\
set DESTPATH=C:\vbk\dest\test

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b ^"%LISTFOLDER%\*.txt^"') do (call :COPY_FILES "%LISTFOLDER%\%%i")

pause
exit

:COPY_FILES
for %%i in (%1) do set DEST=%%~ni
for /r %FILESPATH% %%I in (%1) do echo xcopy /qvs "%%I" "%DESTPATH%\*"
```

Below is a small example of what would be in the .txt file located in LISTFOLDER.

```
01PNK2.PVD
01PR52.PVD
01PVN19.PVD
01PW07S.PVD
01Q0G19.PVD
01Q0W2.PVD
01Q102.PVD
01Q182.PVD
01Q1L2.PVD
...
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first `for` loop in your subroutine `:COPY_FILES` is useless; anyway, the problem is that `for /R` seems to access the file system only in case a wildcard (`*` or `?`) is used in set (that is the part within `()` after `in`); to work around that, you could use the following command line in the subroutine: `for /R "%FILESPATH%" %%I in ("%~1*") do if /I "%~nx1"=="%%~nxI" ECHO xcopy /Q /V /S "%%~fI" "%DESTPATH%\"`

Comment: First off, thanks for the reply @aschipfl. I do understand that `:COPY_FILES` is not necessary.

When replacing the subroutine line (which I assume is the last line in each of my examples above) and running the batch file, it didn't appear to do anything. Am I doing something wrong or placing your subroutine in the wrong place? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just recognised that that the very first `for /F` line should be changed: `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%LISTFOLDER%\listfile.txt") do (call :COPY_FILES "%%~i")` (note that you need to specify _the_ text file here and do not use `*.txt`!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, the following code should do what you want:

```
@echo off

set "LISTFOLDER=C:\vbk\txt\test"
set "FILESPATH=C:\"
set "DESTPATH=C:\vbk\dest\test"

for %%F in ("%LISTFOLDER%\*.txt") do (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%~F") do (
        for /R "%FILESPATH%" %%I in ("%%~L*") do (
            if /I "%%~nxL"=="%%~nxI" (
                ECHO xcopy /Q /V "%%~fI" "%DESTPATH%\"
            )
        )
    )
)
pause
exit /B
```

This is what I did:

- a subroutine (`:COPY_FILES`) is not needed here, so I omitted it;
- `for /F` does not accept wildcards (like `*` or `?`), so I put over a standard `for`;
- the `for /F` loop is intended to read the found text file(s) line by line (at least upon my interpretation of your code), so there is no need for `dir /B`;
- now comes the tricky part: `for /R` walks through a directory tree recursively, searching for matching files given in its set  (that is the part after `in` within `()`); but if a dedicated file is provided there without any wildcards (like `*` or `?`), it does not actually search the file system for the file but merely returns all directories in the tree with the file appended; to force `for /R` to really search the file you need to use a wildcard; so that's why I appended a `*`; but this of course might return unwanted files, namely such that contains the desired name at the beginning; so I placed an `if` statement inside of the loop to filter out the respective items (the `~nx` modifier of the compared `for` variables expand to the pure file names plus extensions only);
- since `for /R` already does the job of walking through a directory tree recursively, you do not need to specify the switch `/S` for `xcopy`; (remove the upper-case `ECHO` to actually copy files!)
- instead of `exit`, you should use `exit /B` within batch files, because this quits the batch file only while `exit` terminates the containing command prompt instance (`cmd`) too; (here `exit /B` is superfluous actually, but I put it here just to be mentioned...)
- the `set` syntax has been improved so that there are quotation marks around the entire assignment expression; this avoids trouble with some special characters like `^` and `&`, for example; note that the `""` do not become part of the variable value here;
- some quotation-mark-related issues have been fixed throughout the script, all paths are enclosed within `""`, and the `~` modifier is used for several `for` variables to remove potential surrounding `""`;

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to copy files listed in some textfiles from wherever they are in a subtree to a particular directory, then

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET "sourcedir=u:"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "listdir=U:\sourcedir"

:: SET $num=name required from list
:: Also maintain extlist
SET "extlist= "
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (
 'type "%listdir%\q34799738*.txt" 2^>nul^|findstr /n /v /L "\"'
) DO (
 SET "$%%a=%%b"
 SET extlist|FIND /i " *%%~xb ">nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL SET "extlist=%%extlist%%*%%~xb "
)

FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%f IN (%extlist%) DO (
 FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO (
  IF /i "%%~nxf"=="%%b" (
   ECHO(COPY "%%f" "%destdir%\%%b"
   SET "%%a="
   SET "continue="
   FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET continue=Y
   IF NOT DEFINED continue GOTO done

  )
 )
) 

:done
FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO(NOT found : %%b

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir`, `listdir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I filtered out the textfiles in `listdir` using `q34799738*.txt` for my testing.

First, read all of the names from the files and assign them to variables named $*number*. The filenames won't contain `:` so `findstr /n` works happily here, numbering the sourcelines.

At the same time, build a list of extensions required. This cuts down the hits found by the following `for /r`. The list is of the form <kbd>space</kbd>*.ext1<kbd>space</kbd>*.ext2<kbd>space</kbd>... so attemting to `find` <kbd>space</kbd>*.newextension<kbd>space</kbd> will miss if the new etension does not exist in the list.

Next, scan the subtree using the extension-list. Look for a match in the `$` variables set. If it's found, then copy the file (the copy is simply `echo`ed for testing), set the `$` variable to *nothing* and check whether there are any `$` variables left set. Continue if yes and go to `done` if not.

At the and, list any still-set `$` variables, as these files were not found.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Comment: I tried using the above in my batch file and it looked like it was working but didn't actually copy the files. Is there and echo I would have needed to remove in order for the copy to work? Other than that, this seems like it would accomplish my issue as well. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yes - I didn't include my standard direction re the `echo(` now done.