# Batch To Copy Files From Source To Destination Using A .txt File

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, command-prompt

Almost ready to give up on this one. :( Open to any new ideas or adjustments.

I have a .txt file listing .pdf files. **No Path..just the file name.
   For each .pdf look in the Source Folder **And Subdirectories** for a
   match. If match found copy .pdf over to destination folder. 
   **Some subdirectories in Source Folder have space in there name.

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
for /f %%i in (File-List.txt) do echo F| xcopy "C:\Source_Folder\%%i"  "c:\Target\%%i"  /i /z /y
```

**RESULT:**
It's looking up the .pdf files but only searching the first directory in the source ..not the subdirectories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch-file to recursively copy many listed files to one specific folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799738/batch-file-to-recursively-copy-many-listed-files-to-one-specific-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f %%a IN ("%sourcedir%") DO SET "drive=%%~da"

for /f "delims=" %%i in (q34868638.txt) do (
REM attrib /s "%sourcedir%\%%i"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('attrib /s "%sourcedir%\%%i"') DO (
  IF "%%a"=="File not found - %drive:~0,1%" (ECHO "%%i" NOT found) ELSE (
  ECHO copy /b "%drive%%%b"  "%targetdir%\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34868638.txt` containing some data for my testing. The filename you use is up to you.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Comment: Magoo this script worked for me. The first answer also worked but gave me problems when dealing searching with 100's of subdirectories and 30GB's of files. I did remove the ECHO before the copy command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a list of subdirectories to search separated by semicolon (like PATH variable)
set "subdirs=C:\Source_Folder"
for /D /R "C:\Source_Folder" %%d in (*) do set "subdirs=!subdirs!;%%d"

rem For each .pdf in the text file
for /F "delims=" %%f in (File-List.txt) do (

   rem Look in the list of subdirectories for a match
   rem see HELP FOR for further details
   for %%p in ("%%f") do set "filePath=%%~$subdirs:p"

   rem If match found
   if defined filePath (
      rem Copy .pdf over to destination folder
      copy "!filePath!" "c:\Target"
   )

)
```

Comment: This script worked fine on my computer..running a small test. When I tried a test on the production server where I have around 30GB of 100's of directories and 1000's of files command prompt will open blink for 1 second and then close? Is there a time out set or something. I tried a small different test script to make sure command prompt was working on that computer and worked fine. I even copied one folder from the massive list and saved it in a separate location. When I ran your script it worked fine. .....so I can only think it has something to do with the number of files being too many?